# Why are the leaves on my peach tree sapling wilting and dropping off?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, indoors, peaches

I have a peach tree and it stopped growing and the leaves started to wilt, but then the tree grew new leaves and they looked great. However, the old leaves kept getting worse. They are now dropping about one a week and I was wondering if I should trim all the poor leaves off it and try to encourage new leaves to grow. I saw it done with a pepper plant before, but didn't know if it will work for a small peach tree.

Here is a picture of the tree. It is a couple of weeks old and the problem has gotten a little bit worse.

[image]

Comment: I can't quite see the pot, but it doesn't look very big - how long have you had this plant and is it growing in or out of doors - and where are you in the world?

Comment: It probably a 2 to 3 gallon pot, I have grown the plant from seed about a year and a half ago, and I live in Canada, so it can never go outside.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar situation with my indoor almond, when I forgot to water the plant for some time. In my case, I did not do anything about it afterwards, just provided regular watering, and wilted leaves all gradually dropped by themselves. However, new growth was strong.

My advice is: *Do nothing*, except regular care, and pay special attention on frequent watering for some period of several weeks. The nature will take care of all the leaves.

It is not uncommon for peach or similar plants to lose leaves that way. The plant endured some form of stress, and that was its defence.

Answer (score 2):

Your tree dropping leaves is very normal.  It is dormancy time so do not fertilize and make sure not to water unless that pot, soil and plant when you lift them are light.

I would think about a new pot, clay.  A few inches in diameter larger.  Use ONLY potting soil out of a bag.  No gravel beneath.  Lift the bottom of the pot off the surface with a few thin chunks of tile.

Have you ever fertilized this plant?  How long have you been growing this plant? Do you have a covered patio?  Shaded porch?  And again, where is it that you live? Do you expect to eat peaches?

Comment: I have fertilized the plant. Its been growing about a year and a half. I don't have anywhere outside to put it since I live in Newfoundland, Canada. So it will never survive our winters and I don't expect to get any peaches. I grew it because I was eating a peach and noticed the pit was broken open and it was allready sprouted a little.

Comment: That is a great reason to grow a peach tree!  If you have a covered porch, shaded patio, you need to put your peach tree out during the summer under a shading roof.  Far more light under a covered porch or patio that will help your plant get through the winter months. Needs to go out only when there is no chance of frost, or bring it in during the nights until the weather gets predictable.  Spending the summer under a roof allows your plant to utilize the extra light to make food to store for the winter.  What did you fertilize it with and what kind of soil are you using in the pot?

Comment: I do have a covered porch, but it is very small, probably no room for the tree. The fertilizer I've used is Jobes fruit & citrus and the soil is Miracle Grow potting soil. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: As long as the covered porch prevents the tree from direct sun it would be the best place during the summer. Even if it is just during the day.  All of my house plants go outside during the summer on a protected, covered porch.  I can't imagine that your covered porch is too small for this baby peach tree.  And the extra light will not make a huge tree out of your guy.  I am talking about moving this tree inside at nights if there is any chance of freezing or wind damage. Leaving it out only if the weather is predictable. Allowing my indoor plants out of doors on a covered area revives them...